# Which gives better deterministic encryption SIV or Plain ECB mode?

Tags: symmetric, ecb, deterministic-encryption, siv

Lets say , if we encrypt a plain text message $msg$ with key $key$ in below two ways. Which is the below would give better deterministic encryption and why ?

1. AES-ECB($key$ , $msg$)
2. SIV($key$, NIL , $msg$) where associated data is NIL.

I could not make out much from Rogaway and Shrimpton's paper on "[Deterministic Authenticated Encryption](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/221)" which introduces Synthentic IV (SIV) mode.

Edit: Here $msg$ is same as single block .

Comment: SIV. As long as an adversary never submits exactly the same message the ciphertext remains indistinguishable from random bits

Comment: same holds good for ECB mode too .

Comment: No, in ECB mode submitting the same block will leak information - rather than SIV where the entire message must be the same to leak information

Comment: ok i meant message and block as same . let me edit the question

Comment: For a single block, ECB is perfectly fine.

Comment: can you explain what use case this is for?  seems rather a strange scenario to me

Comment: Imagine some data type that is 128 bits like say IPv6 address and for some reason i want to encrypt it deterministically.

Comment: If you need strict length preservation you can't use SIV because you need to include the synthetic IV at the beginning.

Comment: @pg1989 yes got it . so i dont have length preservation as criteria . the output could be longer .

Comment: If your input never gets longer than 128 bits, SIV and ECB provide identical security guarantees.

Comment: @pg1989 : $\:$ No; SIV also provides authentication. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Keep it simple and use AES-ECB.

Answer (score 1):

Both:

- Secure deterministic encryption for one-block messages.

ECB:

- No expansion for block-sized messages.
- Faster.

SIV:

- Authentication.
- Works for messages of any size.